# Ternary operator inside static array initialization not working as expected

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I was thinking about dynamically initialize an array in Java using ternary operator in this way:

```
boolean errorMsg = true;
...
String[] elements = new String[] {
    errorMsg ? "single_element" : "1st_element", "2nd_element"
};
```

I just wanted to initialize the array with 1 element if `errorMsg` is `true`, or with 2 elements if errorMsg is `false`.
Whether `errorMsg` is `true` or `false`, it always initializes the `String[]` with the latter two elements. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because `errorMsg ? "single_element" : "1st_element"` resolves to a String and you have another String already `"2nd_element"`.

You need an if else in the place of initialisation of array itself not with the elements inside.

```
String[] elements = errorMsg? new String[] {  "single_element" } : new String[] { "1st_element", "2nd_element" };
```

But to keep my juniours developers happy I'd prefer to write

```
        String[] elements = null;
        if (errorMsg) {
            elements = new String[] { "single_element" };
        } else {
            elements = new String[] { "1st_element", "2nd_element" };
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, I understood clearly . I was just thinking it was possible to return the latter elements jointly "`: "1st_element", "2nd_element"`". but the comma confused me.